# How does the import system works in python?

Tags: python, filesystems

I just created a new environment, and checking the file system I got a bit confused and I have a couple of questions about it.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. As far as I can see, in the '/include' folder it is stored the standard library's headers, right? Also, the installed modules (standard library and third party modules) are in the '/lib/pythonX.Y' folder, right? However, I don't really understand what is the '/bin' folder is for.

Also, as far as I have read, when you install a third party module, it is installed in the folder '/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages'. For example, when installing numpy, the folder '/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/numpy' is created with all the numpy files and with the next structure (shown only the first level):

```
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── __config__.py
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
├── _distributor_init.py
├── _globals.py
├── _pytesttester.py
├── compat
├── conftest.py
├── core
├── ctypeslib.py
├── distutils
├── doc
├── dual.py
├── f2py
├── fft
├── lib
├── linalg
├── ma
├── matlib.py
├── matrixlib
├── polynomial
├── random
├── setup.py
├── testing
├── tests
└── version.py
```

My doubt is, when it is called `import numpy`, which file is being executed/imported? Even more, when importing a submodule, like `from numpy import arange`, what is exactly being done?

Thanks in advance for helping me with these questions.

Comment: Try making a script with some functions, then try importing, and it should answer your question. "Import numpy" imports the .py file, "from numpy import arrange "is to import a determined function from the .py fiile

Comment: `numpy` is a package which defines its public API via the `__init__.py` file, alongside the modules in the package. This is why you can do `from numpy import arange`, there is no `arange.py` file, but the `arange` function is exposed by the package..

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html